# Google sheets filter formula works with one variable, but not with the other

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a sheet that uses a search bar to lookup who has a certain skill. I can select the day I want to lookup with the skill. It works perfect when the variable is set to "zaterdag", but when I select the variable "zondag" it does not work.

I have two backend sheets: Skills_zat and Skills_zon, they are both identical. They just contain other names. According to what day they work.

[This is what it looks like when I select "zaterdag"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro6Ro.png)

[This is what it looks like when I select "zondag"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7qNv.png)

**This is the formula I am using:**

`=IF(O4 = "Zaterdag";IF(N4 = "Troubleshoot Packsize";FILTER(Skills_zat!A2:A;Skills_zat!J2:J=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zaterdag";IF(N4 = "AS Coordinator";FILTER(Skills_zat!A2:A;Skills_zat!B2:B=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zaterdag";IF(N4 = "WMS Coordinator";FILTER(Skills_zat!A2:A;Skills_zat!C2:C=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zaterdag";IF(N4 = "Troubleshoot A";FILTER(Skills_zat!A2:A;Skills_zat!D2:D=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zaterdag";IF(N4 = "AS Troubleshoot Gewicht";FILTER(Skills_zat!A2:A;Skills_zat!F2:F=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zaterdag";IF(N4 = "Troubleshoot Gewicht";FILTER(Skills_zat!A2:A;Skills_zat!F2:F=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zaterdag";IF(N4 = "Troubleshoot B ";FILTER(Skills_zat!A2:A;Skills_zat!E2:E=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zaterdag";IF(N4 = "Troubleshoot B+";FILTER(Skills_zat!A2:A;Skills_zat!K2:K=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zaterdag";IF(N4 = "Dockmaster";FILTER(Skills_zat!A2:A;Skills_zat!G2:G=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zaterdag";IF(N4 = "Bezorgmaster";FILTER(Skills_zat!A2:A;Skills_zat!H2:H=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zaterdag";IF(N4 = "Duitsland";FILTER(Skills_zat!A2:A;Skills_zat!L2:L=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zaterdag";IF(N4 = "Lodge";FILTER(Skills_zat!A2:A;Skills_zat!I2:I=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zaterdag";IF(N4 = "Buddy";FILTER(Skills_zat!A2:A;Skills_zat!M2:M=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zondag";IF(N4 = "Troubleshoot Packsize";FILTER(Skills_zon!A2:A;Skills_zon!J2:J=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zondag";IF(N4 = "AS Coordinator";FILTER(Skills_zon!A2:A;Skills_zon!B2:B=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zondag";IF(N4 = "WMS Coordinator";FILTER(Skills_zon!A2:A;Skills_zon!C2:C=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zondag";IF(N4 = "Troubleshoot A";FILTER(Skills_zon!A2:A;Skills_zon!D2:D=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zondag";IF(N4 = "AS Troubleshoot Gewicht";FILTER(Skills_zon!A2:A;Skills_zon!F2:F=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zondag";IF(N4 = "Troubleshoot Gewicht";FILTER(Skills_zon!A2:A;Skills_zon!F2:F=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zondag";IF(N4 = "Troubleshoot B ";FILTER(Skills_zon!A2:A;Skills_zon!E2:E=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zondag";IF(N4 = "Troubleshoot B+";FILTER(Skills_zon!A2:A;Skills_zon!K2:K=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zondag";IF(N4 = "Dockmaster";FILTER(Skills_zon!A2:A;Skills_zon!G2:G=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zondag";IF(N4 = "Bezorgmaster";FILTER(Skills_zon!A2:A;Skills_zon!H2:H=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zondag";IF(N4 = "Duitsland";FILTER(Skills_zon!A2:A;Skills_zon!L2:L=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zondag";IF(N4 = "Lodge";FILTER(Skills_zon!A2:A;Skills_zon!I2:I=TRUE);IF(O4 = "Zondag";IF(N4 = "Buddy";FILTER(Skills_zon!A2:A;Skills_zon!M2:M=TRUE))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))`

I hope someone has a solution for me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*There's a trailing space as you can see here for `"Troubleshoot B "` within the formula you shared above. Could it be that `Sunday` tab doesn't have this space or so and its just `"Troubleshoot B"` (no ending space)*

Comment: I use the exact same situation for the Saturday. And that works perfectly fine.